# Can RDP and attach debugger, MSVSMON.exe is running, but can't step-into cloud-environment web-role from my unit-test

Tags: wcf, azure, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, azure-web-roles

I have a running `WCF` web role on Azure (not `ASP.NET` hosted!). I've seen many tutorials, tried many of them, and saw many SO questions - none of them seem to match my specific situation:

- I'm able to connect with RDP
- I see the `MSVSMON.exe` process in the host
- I can attach to any process via VS2013-Update4 `Server Explorer` -> `Instance` -> `Attach Debugger...` (which process is the host, btw?)
- The service works: tested with unit-test with the remote service reference
- Disabled firewall - still no luck

I currently use `Azure SDK 2.5`

But when I try to `Step Into` from my unit-test, it says `A remote operation is taking longer than expected` and then: `Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine '*.cloudapp.net' failed. The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.`

What am I missing?

The `csdef` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MyServiceWebRole.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <WebRole name="MyServiceWebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Variable_1" />
      <!-- ... -->
      <Setting name="Variable_N" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

The `Cloud.cscfg` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyServiceWebRole.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <Role name="MyServiceWebRole">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="***" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="***" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2016-10-01T23:59:59.0000000+03:00" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
      <Setting name="Variable_1" value="Variable_1_Value=" />
      <!-- ... -->
      <Setting name="Variable_N" value="Variable_N_Value" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="***" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```